# How to disable the click event in electron app

Tags: events, electron

I am able to built the desktop app in electronJS. I am trying to implement the functionality to disable the click event on window when there is no internet connectivity similar to the slack.I found the [API to detect the internet in electron](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/online-offline-events) but not able to find the way to disable the click events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable all pointer events by adding the following rule to your page's CSS:

```css
body {
  pointer-events:none;
  }
```

or via JavaScript:

```js
document.body.style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

to re-enable:

```css
body {
  pointer-events:auto;
  }
```

or

```js
document.body.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
```

You can do this on more specific elements to gain more granular control.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an invisible panel in front of everything and catch the clicks there.